# MongoDB - PyMONGO update a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, pymongo

collection:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('606df83ba9f0f494a6cf4e19'), 'UID': 'tt0069204', 'TYPE': 'movie', 'startYear': 2003}
{'_id': ObjectId('606df83ba9f0f494a6cf4e20'), 'UID': 'tt0085953', 'TYPE': 'movie', 'startYear': 2003}
{'_id': ObjectId('606df83ba9f0f494a6cf4e21'), 'UID': 'tt0069049', 'TYPE': 'movie', 'startYear': 2003}
{'_id': ObjectId('606df83ba9f0f494a6cf4e22'), 'UID': 'tt0091490', 'TYPE': 'movie', 'startYear': 2003}
{'_id': ObjectId('606df83ba9f0f494a6cf4e23'), 'UID': 'tt0100275', 'TYPE': 'movie', 'startYear': 2003}
```

I need to perform 3 operations on this collection

```
1. Update the TYPE to be tvSeries for where the startyear = 2003
2. Select the documents from the productions collection where the TYPE = tvSeries
3. Using the UID value of the records whose TITLE_TYPE you edited above, 
change the TYPE  ‘realityShow’.
```

I am stuck on the 3rd part. Not sure if the 3rd part of the question is even valid.

Any help with part 3 will be appreciated!

mycode for the first 2 parts

```
import pymongo
import pprint
client=pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db.client.database
collection=db.collection
myquery={"startYear":2003}
newvalues={"$set": {"TYPE":"tvSeries"}}
collection.update_many(myquery,newvalues)
for x in collection.find({"TYPE":"tvSeries"}).limit(5):
    pprint.pprint(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a list of the `UID`s *before* the first update, then use `$in` to perform the second update:

```
myquery = {"startYear": 2003}
newvalues = {"$set": {"TYPE": "tvSeries"}}
uids = [x.get('UID') for x in collection.find(myquery, {'UID': 1})]
collection.update_many(myquery, newvalues)
for x in collection.find({"TYPE": "tvSeries"}).limit(5):
    pprint.pprint(x)

collection.update_many({'UID': {'$in': uids}}, {"$set": {"TYPE": "realityShow"}})
```